# Nested query not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Error Unknown column 'state' in 'field list' but state column is available in database table.

```
//query
SELECT `country` ,GROUP_CONCAT(`state` separator ",") as a
FROM (

SELECT `country` , CONCAT( `state` , ':', GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT `district`
ORDER BY `district` ASC
SEPARATOR ',' ) ) AS NAME
FROM `temp_location`
GROUP BY `country` , `state`
) AS result
GROUP BY `country`
```

Is any other way to work out this query?

Comment: Can you provide the 'temp_location' table structure?

Comment: your subquery doesnt result `state` as column, but in your main query, you select the `state` column..

Comment: Can you provide the exact error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no `state` column in your sub query, try this;)

```
SELECT `country` ,GROUP_CONCAT(`NAME` separator ",") as a
FROM (

SELECT `country` , CONCAT( `state` , ':', GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT `district`
ORDER BY `district` ASC
SEPARATOR ',' ) ) AS NAME
FROM `temp_location`
GROUP BY `country` , `state`
) AS result
GROUP BY `country`
```

***Edited***

```
select `country` ,GROUP_CONCAT(`state` SEPARATOR "//" ) AS `a`
from (
    select
        `country`,
        concat(`state`, ":", GROUP_CONCAT(`district` separator ",")) as `state`
    from `temp_location` 
    group by `country`, `state`) `result`
group by `country`
```

Comment: `You have no status column` - may be a typo.

Comment: i used same query in codeigniter but i  get syntax error again it work in phpmyadmin as=====$this->db->select('ft.country,GROUP_CONCAT(ft.state separator ",") as ColumnName',false);
$this->db->from('(select country, concat(state, ":", GROUP_CONCAT(district separator ",")) as state from temp_location group by country, state) ft');
$this->db->group_by('ft.country');  and error is===========You check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'state)` ft) GROUP BY `ft`.`country`' at line 2

Comment: @riya Could you please format this code in your question? It is too hard to read. :-(

Comment: @riya Seems no syntax error, try to add back quote for every column and table, and tell me the result.

Comment: Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'state` FROM `temp_location` GROUP BY `country`, `state`)` AS `result`) GROUP BY ' at line 2

SELECT `country`, GROUP_CONCAT(`state` SEPARATOR "//" ) AS `a` FROM ((select `country`, concat(`state`, `":"`, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `district` ORDER BY `district` ASC separator ", `")` ) as `state` FROM `temp_location` GROUP BY `country`, `state`)` AS `result`) GROUP BY `cou

Comment: @riya Wow, is there any different between yours and mine. It's weird.

Answer (score 2):

Your subquery does not return a column `state`, only the columns `country` and `NAME`.

Answer (score 2):

Your sub query missed the column name `state` try to change the `NAME` to `state`. Check the below updated query,

```
    SELECT `country` ,GROUP_CONCAT(`state` separator ",") as a
        FROM (SELECT `country`, CONCAT(`state` , ':', 
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `district` ORDER BY `district` ASC 
               SEPARATOR ',')) AS `state`
            FROM `temp_location` GROUP BY `country`, `state`) AS result
        GROUP BY `country`
```